# Написание поиска на MVC PHP

Tags: php, mvc, поиск

Всем привет! Пытаюсь реализовать поиск на MVC PHP. Но даже представления о реализации нет, прошу помочь!
Суть такова: мне надо сделать так, чтобы форма обрабатывалась на любой странице. Я уже почти Junior в PHP.
Вот html разметка формы:

```
<div class="__header__search">
<form action="/posts/search" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Что ищем? ... вкладки, chrome, psd" required minlength="3" maxlength="30">
<button name="sendSearch" type="submit"><img src="/public/images/icons/search.png"></button>
</form>
</div>
```

Все должно обрабатываться в контроллере.

Comment: И где ваш контроллер? В чём проблема, собственно?

Comment: @InDevX В контроллере просто метод, который является action, там будет происходить описание всего поиска. А пока мне просто надо понять, как реализовать поиск. Потому что, эта форма отказывается работать из - за отправки через AJAX. Я так полагаю, потому что есть ошибка Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Comment: Эта ошибка означает что у вас до вывода json ответа уже что-то выводится. Откройте network и посмотрите что приходит в ответ.

Comment: @InDevX уже пробовал, там пустота

Comment: Статус ответа какой? не 500, случаем?